# How to do animated buttons similar to Path on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uikit, caanimation

In the Path iphone application, on the bottom left corner, there is a + sign button.  When pressing it, it performs an animation (the + rotates and a bunch of other buttons emerge outwards).

For those that have seen these types of animations, how is this accomplished?  Is this done via CAAnimations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would definitely want to use either Core Animation, or UIView's animation methods (which use Core Animation under the hood).

Check out https://github.com/levey/QuadCurveMenu to see one attempt to reimplement it.

Comment: Thank you!   That sample is perfect!